# explain this macro

Tags: c++, mfc, file-io, string

```
#define __T(x)      L ## x
```

Found in code from one of the MFC source header file. It is mostly used for converting strings to ........ (I don't know what). If I am correct it converts strings to LPCTSTR...don't know what that type is either...

I can't seem to convert char* into LPCTSTR. While MFC file handling, the following code will always return error while trying to open the file...

```
    char* filepath = "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\BITMAPS\\STYLES\\GLOBE.WMF";

    if( !file.Open((LPCTSTR)filepath , CFile::modeRead, &fexp) )
    {
        fexp.ReportError();
        return 1;
    }
```

But instead if I wrote it this way, it doesn't give error:

```
    if( !file.Open( _T("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\Office12\\BITMAPS\\STYLES\\GLOBE.WMF") , CFile::modeRead, &fexp) )
    {
        fexp.ReportError();
        return 1;
    }
```

I am looking at passing a variable as the first argument to the CFile::Open() method.

Comment: By the way, you're not, in any way, 'converting' from `char *` to `LPCTSTR` with that cast you threw in there. You're forcing the compiler to view the supplied bytes in the way you think they should be viewed rather than in the way the compiler's type system currently understands them. It would, IMHO, have been far far worse if the cast had appeared to work since then you would have thought that simply throwing in a cast to force the code to compile was a good thing. It isn't, ever. You should ALWAYS understand what you're doing before adding a cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ## operator is a preprocessor concatenation operator. That is, this is valid code:

```
#define DECLARE_PTR(X) typedef std::auto_ptr<X> X##Ptr
DECLARE_PTR(int); // gets expanded to typedef std::auto_ptr<int> intPtr
intPtr i(new int(1));
```

In your case, the `_T` macro prepends the Long conversion symbol (`L`) to the input given. This only works with string literals. That means you can't write

```
char* str = "ABC";
wchar_t* wstr = _T(str); // error: Lstr is undefined
```

but you can safely write

```
char* str = "ABC";
LPTSTR wstr = _T("ABC"); // OK, gets expanded to wchar_t * wstr = L"ABC";
                         // when UNICODE is defined
                         // and char * wstr = "ABC"; when unicode is not defined
```

The `L` operator is a convertor of char and char* literals to a Long representation (from `byte`-wide representation to `sizeof(wchar_t)`-wide representation).

Comment: still want to know how to convert an ANSI string to unicode programmatically

Comment: Have a look at `MultiByteToWideChar` and `WideCharToMultiByte`. If you're using WinAPI in your code, these two should suffice. 

Otherwise:

- to convert ASCII chars from `char*` to `wchar_t*` just cast each char (pseudocode):
    for_each(chr in [source char*]) dest += `wchar_t( chr );`

- to convert from `wchar_t*` to `char*` do the same, as long as the `char` values are only in the ANSI subset (convert each `wchar_t` to `char` and append the value to the destination `char*`).

- if you want generic character conversion you need to handle different code pages (i.e. I don't know :( ).

Answer (score 1):

The macro is simply stringizing L with the argument so that:

```
_T("xyz")
```

becomes:

```
L"xyz"
```

This is the way to make a `wstring` but, in the non-Unicode versions, `_T` will map to nothing, so you'll get regular strings there.

Answer (score 1):

`_T()` allows you to set up your string literals so that you can build as either Unicode or non-unicode.

In non-unicode builds it evaluates to nothing so a string literal is represented as `"XYZ"` which is a normal narrow string. In a unicode build it evaluates to `L` (`L"XYZ"`) which tells the compiler that the string literal is a wide character string. This and the various "T" string typedefs `LPCTSTR` etc. Allow you to write code that builds correctly for unicode and non-unicode builds.

Note that google is your friend, simply typing `_T` into google gives [several](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&q=_T&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) useful results...